# How to overload the ->* operator?

Tags: c++

I tried this, and some variations on it:

```
template<class T>
class Ptr {
public:
    Ptr(T* ptr) : p(ptr) {}
    ~Ptr() { if(p) delete p; }

    template<class Method>
    Method operator ->* (Method method)
    {
        return p->*method;
    }

private:
    T *p;
};

class Foo {
public:
    void foo(int) {}
    int bar() { return 3; }
};

int main() {
    Ptr<Foo> p(new Foo());

    void (Foo::*method)(int) = &Foo::foo;
    int (Foo::*method2)() = &Foo::bar;

    (p->*method)(5);
    (p->*method2)();

    return 0;
}
```

But it [doesn't work](http://ideone.com/oUJLG). The problem is that I don't really know what to expect as a parameter or what to return. The standard on this is incomprehensible to me, and since Google did not bring up anything helpful I guess I'm not alone.

*Edit:* Another try, with C++0x: http://ideone.com/lMlyB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The return of `operator->*` represents a function in the process of being called, with the only missing parts being the parameters. Thus, you must return a functor that invokes the given function on the given object with the given parameters:

```
// PTMF = pointer to member function
template<class Obj>
struct PTMF_Object{
  typedef int (Obj::*ptmf)(double,std::string); // example signature

  PTMF_Object(Obj* obj, ptmf func)
    : obj_(obj)
    , func_(func)
  {}

  int operator()(double d, std::string str){
    return (obj_->*func_)(d,str);
  }

  Obj* obj_;
  ptmf func_;
};

template<class T>
struct SmartPtr{
  // ...

  PTMF_Object<T> operator->*(PTMF_Object<T>::ptmf func){
    return PTMF_Object<T>(p, func);
  }
  // ...
};

int main(){
  SmartPtr<Foo> pf(new Foo());
  typedef int (Foo::*Foo_ptmf)(double,std::string);
  Foo_ptmf method = &Foo::bar;

  (pf->*method)(5.4, "oh hi");
}
```

**Edit2**
[Here](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Oct_1999.pdf) is an excellent pdf from Scott Meyers on this very topic (it's the only good literature on overloading `operator->*`, even though it's from 1999).

**Edit**
Here is one, if your compiler supports variadic templates: http://ideone.com/B6kRF

Comment: Sounds scary. I'll have to take a look.

Comment: @Fozi: Believe me, it is. Though the paper I just can't find has a full implementation in it, and your smart pointer only needs to inherit from a certain base and all `operator->*` functionality will be there. :|

Comment: I actually have a Delegate class that might be able to do that, but it's quite heavyweight so I would like to avoid to return it as a temporary. `(*p).*method` is a lot simpler, although I hoped I could support `->*` easily.

Comment: @Fozi: If you can use variadic templates, try the one in the edit I just put together. :) And if your compiler doesn't, you need to emulate it by specializing the `PTMF_Object` by hand for the number of arguments.

Comment: This looks promising. The problem is we don't use c++0x *yet*. Thanks.

Comment: @Fozi: Then try the updated one, you just need to expand it for argument count >= 3. :)

Comment: @Fozi: Bam, article found! :) That paper is really really helpful in understanding how that operator works and how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

I came back to this problem and I found a simple solution:

```
template<class Ret, class... Args>
auto operator ->* (Ret (T::*method)(Args...)) -> std::function<Ret(Args...)>
{
  return [this, method](Args&&... args) -> Ret {
    return (this->p->*method)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  };
}
```

The implementation of the full test case can be found [here](http://ideone.com/A134J).

The only thing I don't like in this solution is the use of `std::function`. If someone knows a way to return the lambda directly, please let me know. I have a hunch that it might not be possible because of the way lambda types are defined though.

Comment: Just don't specify a return type. Since you only have a single `return` statement, the return type is automatically deduced to the inner lambda's type. Otherwise, +1 for the solution. :)

Comment: @Xeo That only works for lambdas, but I must specify the return type for the operator `->*`, which is a `decltype(<my lambda>)`, but the lambda can not be specified there because it's using `this` and besides each lambda instance has its own type. :(

Comment: Oh, right, I overlooked something. :( I don't think you'll get around that `std::function`, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, the return type of `operator->*` should be an object which is callable as a function.

So you may have to forward the pointer to member function invocation to an object which overloads `operator()` (a closure), which is especially painful if you don't have variadic templates handy.

If you have C++0X, you have closures and variadic templates and your problem can be solved with a few lines of generic code.

If you don't, you will have to use macro trickery to simulate variadic templates, and this is **not** fun to do (even if some people think the opposite).

Comment: If I go the C++0x path, shouldn't p->*method already return the right object? Would an auto return type not be enough? http://ideone.com/lMlyB Again, I'm stuck.

Comment: @Fozi: Very good point. Maybe. I'm not C++0x savvy enough, bud I'd say yes, that would do the trick. Or maybe `decltype` would work too.